# Read a mysql table with 31 different columns

Tags: php, mysql

I need to read a table which represent a monthly register. somenting like

```
year, month, name, d1...d31 <--days of the month
```

I use this function to obtain the global hours of the month

```
function calchour($db, $table, $year, $month)
{
    $daysinmonth =cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);//Nbr of days in month
    $tt_hour = '0';
    $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM $table WHERE anno = '$year' AND month = '$month'") or merror($msg = mysqli_error($db));  
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $volhr = '0';
        for ($i = '1'; $i <= $daysinmonth; $i++) {
            $day = 'd'.$i;
            $hour = $row[$day];
            if (($hour != '')) { $volhr = $volhr + $hour; }
        }
        $tt_hour = $tt_hour + $volhr;
    }
return $tt_hour;    
}
```

Is there a better way to obtain the global hour for the month?

Comment: are d29,d30,d31 0 or null in the database for months that don't have those days?  or might they have values that you need to ignore?

Comment: Not all days are filled with a value. I evaluate only cells with a value `if (($hour != '')) { $volhr = $volhr + $hour; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just add them up in sql:

```
SELECT SUM(
    coalesce(d1,0)+coalesce(d2,0)+coalesce(d3,0)+coalesce(d4,0)+coalesce(d5,0)+coalesce(d6,0)+coalesce(d7,0)+coalesce(d8,0)+coalesce(d9,0)+coalesce(d10,0)+coalesce(d11,0)+coalesce(d12,0)+coalesce(d13,0)+coalesce(d14,0)+coalesce(d15,0)+coalesce(d16,0)+coalesce(d17,0)+coalesce(d18,0)+coalesce(d19,0)+coalesce(d20,0)+coalesce(d21,0)+coalesce(d22,0)+coalesce(d23,0)+coalesce(d24,0)+coalesce(d25,0)+coalesce(d26,0)+coalesce(d27,0)+coalesce(d28,0)+coalesce(d29,0)+coalesce(d30,0)+coalesce(d31,0))
) total_hours ...
```

Though it would be even better to reorganize your database to have a separate row for each value.  Any time you have columns named column1, column2, etc, it is a sign of bad database design.  So something like:

```
 create table volhours (
     date date not null primary key,
     volhours int
 );
```

And select total hours for a range of dates:

```
 select coalesce(sum(volhours),0) total_hours from volhours where date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31';
```

And of course you should be using placeholders.

Comment: I understand that the DB was not the best design but it was the only idea I found to represent a month. I will appreciate if you can give me a better design. Dont hany problem to redesign the DB and rewrite the code

Comment: there's no need to represent a month; your data is just dates and numbers of hours for each date.  month is only something you need to worry about when deciding which records to select

Comment: Correct, but if I need to know how many hours `foo = $row[name]` worked on day 21? I have about 20 "names" many of them may change every month

Comment: then you select just the row you want.  I'm not sure what the names are that you refer to or how that fits in?  can you explain more?

Comment: Following is an example of the report I need to prepare each month.[link] (https://i.imgur.com/NrH2zMI.jpg)

Comment: Sorry forgot to insert the db structure (https://i.imgur.com/kAkRThH.jpg)